# root type undefined running typescript-json-schema

Tags: typescript

When running the command `typescript-json-schema --noExtraProps --required --refs false -o ./types.schema.json ./tsconfig.json *` for the typescript-json-schema npm package the command fails with the error:

```
Error: Not supported: root type undefined
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getDefinitionForRootType (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:473:27)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getTypeDefinition (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:1127:26)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getDefinitionForRootType (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:560:53)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getTypeDefinition (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:1127:26)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getUnionDefinition (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:721:32)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getTypeDefinition (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:1098:26)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getDefinitionForProperty (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:594:31)
    at\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:908:37
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at JsonSchemaGenerator.getClassDefinition (\node_modules\typescript-json-schema\dist\typescript-json-schema.js:906:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused because type utilities for schemas support optional properties, but not unions with undefined. This for example will cause that error:

```ts
interface car {
 model:string | undefined;
}
```

your types will need to look like this instead:

```ts
interface car {
 model?:string;
}
```

There is a relevant github issue dealing with the same thing in ajv [here](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/2040#issuecomment-1192465408).